# Best way to get peak g-force from accelerometer every second in Android?

Tags: java, android

What is the best way for me to get a peak g-force reading on my android device every second? I have managed to get X, Y and Z values from the device but I'm wondering how I can detect peak g-force (with the direction in which it peaked as well).

Comment: u need to calculate angular velocity using the 3 dimesional space first.(I guess it is possible to calculate the direction of this vector as well).later square of W multiple with the radious (r).

Answer (score 0):

You already have the magnitudes of the three components of the acceleration vector `(ax, ay, az)`.  If you understood the orientations of the unit vectors for the `(X, Y, Z)` coordinate system you'd have all you needed to calculate the magnitude and direction of the acceleration vector.

Comment: Can you provide a code example for doing this in Java?

Comment: Your issue is a lack of understanding of vectors.  I'd fix that first.